# Put Method To Update A 'Hotel' Object Ends With System.Text.Json.JsonException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dapper

Put request is handled very well as far as I have observed but something goes wrong after an updated hotel object is passed to HotelManager layer from HotelRepository.

That's the error: *System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.*

here is the code in HotelRepository:

```
public async Task<int> UpdateHotel(Hotel hotel)
    {
        var sql = "UPDATE Hotels " +
                    "SET name = @name, city = @city " +
                    "WHERE Id = @id";

        var updatedHotel = new Hotel()
        {
            Name = hotel.Name,
            City = hotel.City,
            Id = hotel.Id
        };

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
        {
            return await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, updatedHotel);
        }
    }
```

At first I though it was about the spaces in the sql commands. I realized I did not add any spaces after the ends of the lines so I fixed that but I guess that's not the issue since I still get the same error.

The other routes work well.

Hotel object in the request contains id, name, and city.
Do you know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> That's the error: *System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32.*

You can try to install the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/3.1.10) NuGet package to add support for `Newtonsoft.Json` based features, and check if it can help fix above issue.

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```